# How to make a button responsive in react component without using react-bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, onclick, uibutton

I need a help, need to make a button responsive without using react-bootstrap. Under the following criteria and struggling to achieve this on react component function.

// Criteria

> If the value is 0, - butoon should be grayed out and non-clickable. If
> the value is 3 and you press + value changes to 4. if an incorrect
> value is entered using input field(e.g -10),  on blur-event that value
> should change to last valid valued used instead

.

// function component

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState} from 'react';
function Footer() {
    // buttons to decrease and increase 
     const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);  
     const incrementCount = () => {  
       // Update state with incremented value  
       setCounter(counter + 1);  
     };  
     const decrementCount = () => {  
       // Update state with incremented value  
       setCounter((c) => Math.max(c - 1, 0));  
     }; 

   return(){
      <>
        <div className="btn-group" role="group"> <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" onClick={decrementCount} > - -</button>  
        <input type="number" min="1" defaultValue={counter} className="form-control" />  
        <button  type="button"  className="btn btn-warning"  onClick={incrementCount} > + </button> 
      </>

     }




}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? It looks like you're missing an onBlur event listener. Also sounds like perhaps you should add a checkForZero function that adds a "disabled" class (or removes it if the value isn't 0).

Comment: @VividlyFaced, well my question how to make buttons clickable and no-clickable by having these as a responsive, then my button should indeed have onBlur event listener but i dont know how to achieve this and need help based on in what i have

Comment: to disable/enable button use this: `<button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" onClick={decrementCount} disabled={counter == 0}>-</button>`

Comment: @DINk74 have implemented this as well, can anyone perhaps replicate this code and show me what am i missing as per my criteria because to me the buttons are not clickable to + and -